# Windows 2003 determine which app is trying to reach remote macine

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003

I have following question: on my firewall i can see connections from my win 2003 server:

```
 Feb  8 15:18:53 gw kernel: [5197300.553485]  **LEGACY** IN=tun6 OUT=vlan1    SRC=192.168.70.195 DST=192.168.8.179 LEN=106 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=126 ID=11183 PROTO=UDP  SPT=3611 DPT=161 LEN=86
```

But i can't see this traffic from win 2003 (192.168.70.1) with netstat or with TCPView
What else can be done to find source application for this traffic?

Answer (score 0):

Install Microsoft Network Monitor on the server in question, start a capture, and look for the process responsible for the traffic.